# Adding onclick event handler to dynamically added button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am adding a button dynamically to HTML as shown below.

When clicking that button I want to call a JavaScript function.

```
var but = document.createElement("button");

but.value="delete row";

but.setAttribute("onclick","callJavaScriptFunction()");
// this is not working

but.onclick="callJavaScriptFunction()"
// this is also not working

document.getElementById("but").onclick="callJavaScriptFunction()"
// this is also not working

but.id="but"+inc;
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this:

```
but.onclick = callJavascriptFunction;
```

or create the button by wrapping it with another element and use innerHTML:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = '<button id="but' + inc +'" onclick="callJavascriptFunction()" />';
```

Comment: dude everything is ok.. But I am not able to give the ID by concatinating the string : but and inc... Plz help......          "but' + inc +'"  this is not working

Comment: try : span.firstChild.setAttribute("but" + inc); after the span.innerHTML, also i assume that inc is a variable, and that must be set before it is used. let me know it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: how to add params to callJavascriptFunction() like callJavascriptFunction(p1,p2,p3)

Comment: It works, but how! What's the difference between `btn.onclick = function_name();` and `btn.onclick = function_name`.

Answer (score 16):

Remove the () from your expressions that are not working will get the desired results you need.

```
but.setAttribute("onclick",callJavascriptFunction);
but.onclick= callJavascriptFunction;
document.getElementById("but").onclick=callJavascriptFunction;
```

Comment: Why the setAttribute when you also do onclick? Dont all browsers just support onclick?

Comment: when sending a parameter for function how to call function

Answer (score 11):

This code work good to me and look more simple. Necessary to call a function  with specific parameter.

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");  //<button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("MyButton"); // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);   

btn.onclick = function(){myFunction(myparameter)};  
document.getElementById("myView").appendChild(btn);//to show on myView
```

Answer (score 6):

Try
`but.addEventListener('click', yourFunction)`
Note the *absence* of parantheses `()` after the function name. This is because you are assigning the function, not calling it.

Answer (score 5):

`but.onclick = function() { yourjavascriptfunction();};`

or

`but.onclick = function() { functionwithparam(param);};`

Comment: > The significant drawback with inline events is that unlike event listeners described above, you may only have one inline event assigned. Inline events are stored as an attribute/property of the element[doc], meaning that it can be overwritten. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/1872046)

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue but none of these fixes worked.  The problem was that my button was not yet on the page.  The fix for this ended up being going from this:

```
//Bad code.
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.onClick = function() {  console.log("hey");  }
```

to this:

```
//Working Code.  I don't like it, but it works. 
var btn = document.createElement('button');
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.appendChild(btn);

document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
var buttons = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");
buttons[0].onclick = function(){  console.log("hey");  }
```

I have no clue at all why this works.  Adding the button to the page and referring to it any other way did not work.

Comment: I made this answer a very long time ago, and would no longer recommend it.  Instead, use `btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){ do stuff });`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var inputTag = document.createElement("div");              
inputTag.innerHTML = "<input type = 'button' value = 'oooh' onClick = 'your_function_name()'>";    
document.body.appendChild(inputTag);
```

This creates a button inside a DIV which works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
but.onclick = callJavascriptFunction;
```

no double quotes no parentheses.

Comment: what if you want arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Using modern JavaScript, this solution works well:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btnID");
btn.onclick = () => {onAction(url, method);};
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this works!

button.onclick = () => (removechore());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).