# how to call onclick function on dynamically created button in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, dynamically-generated

```
var del = document.createElement('input');
del.type = 'button';
del.name = 'delll';
del.value = 'del';
del.onClick = 'alert("hi  javascript")';
```

Here I have dynamically created a input type BUTTON and now I want to call function on button click event. I am using `onClick();` function for this. In the above code all is working fine but `del.onclick` is not working as I want (for generating alert for demo)

I am not using any jquery code in this program so please don't use any jquery code.

Comment: Take a look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956258/adding-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set the onclick (all lower case) to an anonymous function

```
del.onclick = function(){ alert('hi javascript');};
```

note the function is not in quotes like other attributes

Answer (score 3):

```
del.onclick = function () {
    alert("hi  jaavscript");
};
```

Use small `"C"` in `onClick` and pass a function for it.

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nX67s/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
    var del = document.createElement('input');
    del.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    del.setAttribute('name', 'delll');
    del.setAttribute('value', 'del');
    del.setAttribute('onClick', 'alert("hi  jaavscript")');
```

Answer (score 0):

So to answer the question in details:

del.onclick = '' does not "execute" something within quotes.
If you want to execute/call a function, you would want to pass the function as a parameter.

i.e

```
del.onclick = function() { alert('hi there!')}
```